# Inserting CoreML model in project results in errors

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, coreml, createml

I want to insert a CoreML model into my Swift project. But whenever I insert a model and build my project I run into "Swift Compiler Errors" with the auto generated model class files for the mlmodel. There are four errors regardless of any model I add to the project

In the auto-generated file there is a Line:

```
try! self.init(contentsOf: type(of:self).urlOfModelInThisBundle)
```

It throws the errors - 
1. Incorrect argument label in the call (have 'of:', expected 'rawValue:')
2. Value of type 'type?' has no member 'urlOfModelInThisBundle'

Comment: Which version of Xcode are you using?

Comment: Xcode 11.4.1. In fact, if I create a new simple project and load the same model, it works without any error.

Comment: Do you have another class inside the project that has the same name as the model?

Comment: Nope. Besides, I tried multiple models. Regardless of what model I insert, the same errors pop up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it. Got around the issue by disabling auto generation of the class file. I created a manual Swift file and pasted the same code from the generated file. Just changed up the syntax of that error line into:

```
try! self.init(contentsOf: model_className.urlOfModelInThisBundle)
```

This worked perfectly and now I am able to use the model in my project.

But this still doesn't explain why the error popped up in the first place.